# Is a*b* regular?

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

I know a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> for n > 0 is not regular by the pumping lemma but I would imagine `a*b*` to be regular since both a,b don't have to be the same length. Is there a proof for it being regular or not?

Comment: Well you could easily construct a DFA to recognise it, so yes it is regular.

Comment: @Lee no need to write DFA regular expression is possible only for regular language and `a*b*` is regular expression

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Yes, and regular expressions describe languages which can be recognised by a DFA.

Comment: It's just an arbitrary decision, how you define regular languages - by REs, DFAs or regular grammars.

Comment: @Elazar else non is needed,  Best/objective  way to know the class of a language by analyze pattern of language whether some suffix sub-string depends on some part of prefix sub-string. That is kind of dependency whether it require finite or infinite memory to remember prefix part etc..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan this is very useful method, but it is not a proof (the way to prove that you only need finite memory is to build a DFA and prove its language. the way to prove the contrary is with the pumping lemma).

Comment: @Elazar yup are called formal proofs...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Answer to your question:

> imagine **a*b*** to be regular, Is there a proof for it being regular or not?

No need to imagine, expression  `a*b*` is called [**r**egular **e**xpression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (re), and regular expressions are possible only for regular languages. If a language is not regular then regular expression is also not possible for that and if a language is regular language then we can always represent it by some regular expression.

Yes, `a*b*` represents a regular language.

**Language description**: Any number of **`a`** followed by any numbers of **`b`** (by *any number* I mean zero (including null `^`) or more times). Some example strings are:

```
{^, a, b, aab, abbb, aabbb, ...}
```

DFA for RE `a*b*` will be as follows:

```
      a-            b-
      ||            ||
      ▼|            ▼|
---►((Q0))---b---►((Q1))

In figure: `(())` means final state, so both `{Q0, Q1}` are final states.
```

You need to understand following basic concept:

#### What is basically a regular language? And why an infinite language `a*b*` is regular whereas languages like `{ a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n > 0 }` are not regular!!

A language(a set) is called regular language, if it requires only bounded(finite) amount of information to keep store at any instance of time while processing strings of the language.

So, what is 'bounded' information?
For example: Consider a fan 'on'/'off' switch. By viewing fan switch we can say whether the fan is in the `on` or `off` state (this is bounded or limited information). But we cannot tell 'how many times' a fan has been switched to `on` or `off` in the past! (to memorize this, we require a mechanism to store an 'unbounded' amount of information to count — 'how many times' e.g. the meter used in our cars/bikes).

The language { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n > 0 } is **not** a regular language because here `n` is unbounded(it can be infinitely large). To verify strings in the language a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>, we need to memorize how many **`a`** symbols there are and it requires an infinite memory storage to count because the number of **`a`** symbols in the string can be infinitely large!

That means an automata is only capable of processing strings of the language a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> if it has infinite memory e.g PDA.

Whereas, `a*b*` is of course regular by its nature, because there is the bounded restriction ‐ that **`b`** may come after some **`a`** ( and `a` can't came after `b`). And that is why every string of this language can be easily processed (or recognized) by an automata in which we have finite memory - and  **finite automata** is a class of automata where memory is finite. Yes, in finite automata, we have finite amount of memory in the term of states.

(*Memory in finite automata is present in the form of states `Q` and according to automata principal: any automata can have only finite states. hence finite automata have finite memory, this is the reason the class of automata for regular languages is called finite automata. You can think of a finite automata like a CPU without memory, that has finite  register to remember its internal states*)

Finite State ⇒ Finite Memory ⇒ Only language can be processed for which finite memory needs to store at any instance of time while processing the string ⇒ that language is called Regular Language

Absent of external memory is limitation of finite automate ⇒ or we can say limitation of finite automata defined class of language called Regular Language.

You should read other answer ["finiteness of regular language"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818068/1673391) to learn scope of regular language.

**side note:**:

- language { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n > 0 } is subset of `a*b*`
- Also a language { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | 10<sup>>100</sup> n > 0 } is regular, a large set but regular because `n` is bounded, hence finite automata and regular expression is possible for this language.

You should also read: [**How to prove a language is regular?**](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular)

Comment: @someonewithpc No, regex in programming languages are not regular language (about which I am talking here). Actually language defined by programming language Regex is  (it is a linear CFG) super set of Regular languages. "class of language defined by Regex" ⊇ 'regular languages'. Regex in programming is not exact same as Regular expression in formal languages.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is: `((a*)(b*))` is a well-formed regular expression, hence matching a regular language. `a*b*` is a syntactic shortenning of the same expression.

Another proof: Regular languages are closed to concatenation. a* is a regular language. b* is a regular language, therefore their concatenation, a*b*, is also a regular expression.

You can build an automat for it:

```
0 ->(a) 1
0 ->(b) 2
1 ->(a) 1
1 ->(b) 2
2 ->(b) 2
2 ->(a) 3
3 ->(a,b) 3
```

where only 3 is not an accepting state, and prove that the language is a*b*.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that a language is regular, it is sufficient to show either:

1) There exists some DFA that recognizes it. In this case, the DFA is trivial.

2) The language can be expressed as a regular expression, as mentioned in another answer. `a*b*` is a regular expression to recognize this language.

Answer (score 0):

A regular language is a language that can be expressed with a regular expression or a deterministic or non-deterministic finite automata or state machine. 
A language is a set of strings which are made up of characters from a specified alphabet, or set of symbols. Regular languages are a subset of the set of all strings.

a closure property is a statement that a certain operation on languages, when applied to languages in a class (e.g., the regular languages), produces a result that is also in that class.

this RE shows..the type of language that accepts multiple of (a) if any but before (b)

means **language without containing any substring (ba)**

Comment: You give a lot of definitions, but I think you make the wrong conclusion. The question was whether `a*b*` is regular, and I think it is (but simply because it does not require any backtracking or unlimited look-ahead. Maybe improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regular languages are not subset of context free languages. For example, a*b* is regular, comprising all the strings made of substring of a's followed by substring of b's. This is not subset of a^nb^n, but superset.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).