# Given a language a^n b^m such that n and m have some relation between them implies that the given language can not be regular.Am i correct?

Tags: automata, context-free-language

I know what regular and context free language are and how regular language needs finite memory, and other related stuff. What concerns me is that I think if a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup>  such that `n` and `m` have some relation between them then they can not be regular, but I cant find any such  thing written anywhere. Am I correct to state so?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CS theory (try http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: May be u r right sir but at least programmers can have their say on the topic.

Comment: Yes you are correct. To argu the fact you need  to explain limitations of Finite Automata (class of automata for regular languages) and need to explain what is called regular language. I have answered this: [What is basically a regular language? And Why `a*b*` is regular? But languages like `{ a^nb^n | n > 0 }` is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723185/is-ab-regular/16730707#16730707)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan sir i beg to differ not on the answer you gave but on this question being duplicate .My point was that given every relation between 'n' and 'm'  can we imply that the language is not regular?Or are there relations for which this hypothesis fails.can we categorize those relations.

Comment: @sandeepbisht that is what I answered their! .... to categorize those relations you just need to understand limitations of finite automata. -- a^na^m may be a regular or a *not* regular. A language will not be regular if information about `n` has be stored unbound.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i know  "...information about n has be stored unbound"

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan sir i know  "...information about n has be stored unbound" I was expecting some more information on relationship between n and m .....example of a relationship between n and m which make  a^n b^n regular...n=m mod 15 may be an example(i think it is ) other such examples...and then categorize them.

Comment: @sandeepbisht :( if it doesn't answer you. You may like to ask CS.stackexchange