# Why {a^nb^n | n>=1} is not a regular language?

Tags: regular-language

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSczX111n3U#t=08m08s) video, and wonder why {a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n≥1} is not a regular language?

[image]

Comment: This is probably a better fit on [cs.se]

Comment: You are confused if you think that the diagram you show recognizes a^nb^n

Comment: sorry...my bad. I will close it now..

Comment: @Blake After two fellow StackOverflow users have spent time answering? How unneighborly!

Comment: @PascalCuoq  that is to avoid more users spending time reading my mistake

Comment: @Blake read [What is basically a regular language? And why an infinite language `a*b*` is regular whereas languages like `{ anbn | n > 0 }` are not regular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723185/is-ab-regular/16730707#16730707)

Comment: Why not accept one of the answers; this will save more users from answering also....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the definition of “regular language” as “recognized by a finite automaton”, let m be the number of states of such an automaton. If the automaton is to recognize a<sup>1</sup>b<sup>1</sup>, a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>2</sup>, …, a<sup>m+1</sup>b<sup>m+1</sup>, the states of the automaton cannot be the same after it has read a<sup>1</sup>, a<sup>2</sup>, …, a<sup>m+1</sup>, leading to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Regular language must be recognized by finite automaton. As `n` is not bounded by any constant the automaton cannot be finite.