# Will L = {a*b*} be classified as a regular language?

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

Will L = {a*b*} be classified as a regular language?

I am confused because I know that L = {a^n b^n} is not regular. What difference does the kleene star make?

Comment: This might be better suited for the "Language Learning" Stack...

Comment: I will edit it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well it is makes difference when you have a `L = {a^n b^n}` and a `L = {a*b*}`.

When you have a `a^n b^n` language it is a language where you **must** have the same number of `a's` and `b's` example:`{aaabbb, ab, aabb, etc}`. As you said this is not a regular expression.

But when we talk about `L = {a*b*}` it is a bit different here you can have any number of `a` followed by any numbers of `b` (including 0). Some example are:

```
{a, b, aaab, aabbb, aabbbb, etc}
```

As you can see it is different from the `{a^n b^n}` language where you needed to have the same numbers of `a's` and `b's`.

And yes `a*b*` is regular by its nature. If you want a good explanation why it is regular you can check this [How to prove a language is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular) they might have a better explanation then me (:

I hope it helped you

Comment: Found it now, it can be useful to  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723185/is-ab-regular?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The language described by the regular expression a*b* is regular by definition. These expressions cannot describe any non-regular language and are indeed one of the ways of defining the regular languages.

{a^n b^n: n>0} (this would be a formally complete way of describing it) on the other hand, cannot be described by a regular expression. Intuitively, when reaching the border between a and b you need to remember n. Since it is not bounded, no finite-memory device can do that. In a*b* you only need to remember that from now on only b should appear; this is very finite. The two stars in some sense are not related; each expands its block independently of the other.