# Every regular language is finite | True or False?

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata

I tried to solve it using `L=a*`as anti-example, but it seems wrong.

`{0, a, aa, ...}` has to do with the number of strings

any suggestions?

Comment: "..." means there is no end, no? So there are infinitely many words, and you have indeed found a regular language that is not finite.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723185/is-ab-regular/16730707#16730707) and [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23776/is-it-compulsory-that-every-infinite-set-be-non-regular/23782#23782)

Comment: thanks for the links

Answer (score 0):

A regular Language simply means the language consists of finite number of equivalence classes (set partitions) in which the string can be distributed . These strings can be however of any length. There is no limit on the number of strings as well as long as it can be designated to one of the equivalence class. Thus a language can be regular if even if it is infinite.

Answer (score -2):

Finite language means Language of which all strings are of finite length.

> For example language A subset of L which has strings of length atmost 3

Regular language means language of which all strings are recognised by a finite state machine.

> For example L=a* is recognised by FSM.so it will be a Regular language.
>
> So,we can say every finite language is regular,but inverse is not true.

Comment: No, finite language usually means a language with only finitely many strings. Even in an infinite language every single string is of finite length: in a* every a^n has length n - finite. On the other hand there are notions of regularity even for langauages of infinte strings; see Büchi automata.