# Why can regex not be used to describe a recursive structure?

Tags: regex, recursion

Can some explain to me why you can not use regex to describe a recursive structure.

Eg

- A = *A?B

Comment: That's a consequence of the formal definition of a regular language. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language

Comment: @p.s.w.g Careful! Not everything running under the label "regex" is equivalent to regular languages, many are strictly more powerful.

Comment: @delnann while the question is tagged "regex" and has no language-specific question, `p.s.w.g`'s statement is applicable (and in any case is perfectly accurate).

Answer (score 3):

Because a regex (in the sense of regular languages, at least) corresponds to a finite state machine. You'd need an infinite number of states to track arbitrary levels of nesting.

Comment: "regex" no longer means "finite state machine", unless you want to get into a long and fruitless terminology flamewar with half the programming population. Even backtracking breaks that isomorphism, not to mention other extensions.

Comment: @delnan: I realise that ;) but unless qualified further, I assume "regex" means "regular language"...

Comment: It is this assumption I have a problem with. In my experience, the majority uses "regex" to mean "whatever my language(s) support" which in most cases is at least backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

Even though regular expressions cannot express recursion by formal definition, for some languages like Perl and Ruby there are 'regex' [implementations that support recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html).

Also for python there is an [alternative regex implementation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) supporting recursion that's not in the standard lib.

But again, [regular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718202/what-is-a-regular-language) don't have recursive structures, so formally regular expressions cannot express recursive structures by definition.